# How do I turn on Laravel in production using Apache?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, virtualhost

- I have installed Apache, MySQL, PHP, Composer, Laravel, etc. on CentOS 8.
- I have created an Apache VirtualHost that is serving up PHP with https just fine.
- I have a Laravel application in a subdirectory on the VirtualHost and it runs without SSL using `php artisan serve`

My question is: **How do I get it to run on the Apache VirtualHost?**

Do I need to have an index.php redirect or include something?
What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: Did you take a look at any kind of documentation or walkthrough, [such as this](https://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/steps-for-configuring-laravel-on-apache-http-server/)?

Comment: Typically you create a virtual host and set the root directory of the virtual host to be your project's `public` directory. SSL is trickier because you need to install the correct certificates and reference them in your virtual host configuration.

Comment: As @tilleyc and @apokryfos said, the main step is to have your Apache config virtual host's `DocumentRoot` go to `/you_laravel_root_dir/public` and that's it.

Comment: I have spent hours scouring over docs & tutorials, I'm new to Laravel so I didn't realize, I simply had to point it to /public. tysm @matiaslauriti if you make this an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: @n8bar No worries, you reply to your own question with the solution that helped you and mark it as a solution so everyone can see it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to point the virtual host's `DocumentRoot` to `/laravel_app_root/public`
Thanks again, @matiaslauriti